# Coffeescript Directive replace html from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

I am a newbie to both coffeescript and user-defined directives.

JSON Object

```
["Comments": "Some text &#150; more text"]
```

The database has html hyphens "-" in the JSON data being returned.

My Directive:

```
@mWebApp.directive 'customerComments', [ ->
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<li>{{ customer.0.Comments }}</li>'
]
```

My Html in public/templates/customers/show.html

```
<customer-comments></customer-comments>
```

This is what renders:

```
<customer-comments>
  <li>Some text &#150; more text</li>
</customer-comments>
```

Which is great, except for the `&amp;#150;` appearing.

Can I use the directive to find `&amp;#150`; within the JSON data and replace it on the page with an actual hyphen or em-dash "-"